# Facebook graph page events excluding cancelled

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

With the current v2.8 Facebook graph when retrieving /{pageid}/events ... cancelled events are not included is there a way to include them? Is canceled is useless then

Comment: Are you using a page access token?

Comment: I should be? I am logging into fb with my app I'd and secret and curl using client credentials to get an access token which I thought would be a page toke. I could be wrong... I am able to retrieve all information except events that were cancelled it just does not include them

Comment: Try with a page access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: How can I get a page access token from logging in as an app though? We don't have a user logging in as the website is doing all the requests on the backend. Is there a way for app to retrieve a token? Page access tokens say only a user can get a page token

Comment: I retrieved a Page_Access_Token from myself (30 day and then extended it to 60 day for testing), I am an admin of the page... but cancelled events, still do not populate...

Comment: Then file a bug report and ask what’s up with that. developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Facebook Graph API for Pages/Events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/).  It is not very obvious from the document guide, but you need to add the ".include_canceled(true)" into your query URL.  For example, look at the end of the following URL.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/<PageName>?access_token=<AccessToken>&fields=events.include_canceled(true)
```

You can then add special query parameters and limiting to your query.  As a bonus example,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/<PageName>?access_token=<AccessToken>&fields=events.include_canceled(true).limit(10){name,start_time,end_time,description,place,is_canceled,cover,updated_time,attending_count,maybe_count,interested_count}&format=json&method=get&pretty=1
```

Comment: Still works with API v13. Thanks.